# Overloading ostream

Tags: operator-overloading, ostream

I have my class for example TEST
in TEST.h I have

friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const test& outstr);

in TEST.cc

ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, test& strout) {
    out<< "TEST";
    return out;
}

in main
test x;
cout<< x;

I recieve error message:
 error: undefined reference to `operator<<(std::basic_ostream >&, test const&)

whats the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have const in the declaration:

friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, **const** test& outstr);

and no const in the implementation:

ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, **MISSING CONST** test& strout)

Adding const to the implementation should solve your issue.